# what does "0$variable" mean in perl?

Tags: perl

I am looking at a line of code in perl and trying to make sense on what does it actually mean. It looks like following

`$somestring = "0$SomeString" while(length($someString) < 10)`

I understand other parts of this assignment except when it says `0$somestring` here?

Comment: It is called string interpolation. A variable is interpolated into a string constant. See [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for more information. Note that in Perl case matters, so `$somestring` is different from `$SomeString`.

Comment: Maybe the first `$somestring` should be `$someString`? It's going to loop forever otherwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know code-only answers are discouraged...but this seems straightforward enough:

```
£ perl -e '
quote> $mystring = "48";
quote> $mystring = "0$mystring" while(length($mystring)<10);
quote> print "$mystring\n";
quote> '
0000000048
£
```

Answer (score 3):

(Note that, in Perl, `$somestring`, `$SomeString`, and `$someString` are *not* equivalent.  For the purposes of this answer, I'm assuming that all three were meant to be `$somestring`.  If they really were meant to be three separate variables, then the line of code in the question will either do nothing at all or loop forever, depending on the length of `$someString`.)

`$somestring = "0$somestring"` modifies the value of `$somestring` to insert a `0` at the beginning of the string.

With the `while` part added, the overall effect of the line of code you asked about is to pad `$somestring` to a length of 10 characters with leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is just appending 0 to the value of $Something and assigning it to $somestring. 
Note : both variables are different on L.H.S and R.H.S
finally it check if length of variable is less than 10 or more.

Answer (score 1):

Original very perl*ish* version:
`$somestring = "0$SomeString" while(length($someString) < 10)`

Equivalent more readable version:

```
while( length($someString) < 10 ) {
   # prepend "0" to $someString (increases length of $someString by 1) 
   $someString = '0' . $someString; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Left pad](https://metacpan.org/pod/LeftPad) [strikes again](http://www.haneycodes.net/npm-left-pad-have-we-forgotten-how-to-program/).

A saner way of doing this is `$somestring = '0' x (10 - length($somestring)) . $somestring`.

If, `$somestring` is supposed to hold an integer value, and you want to left pad that numeric value with `0`s, you have [sprintf](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html): `sprintf '%010d', $somestring`.

Comment: `sprintf '%010s', $somestring` also works fine, even for non-numeric values.

Comment: @Borodin Did anyone claim otherwise?

Comment: Why do you think I'm claiming that someone did? *"If `$somestring` is supposed to hold an integer value"* seems unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: My example demonstrates the case where `$somestring` is assumed to hold an integer value, so it is exactly as restrictive as it needs to be. For other possible alternatives, the interested reader can consult the manual. The answer is in three parts: 1) I identify what problem the original snippet is attempting to solve; 2) I show a way of doing it without loops and without using any other function than `length` which is already in the original snippet; and 3) I point the OP to `sprintf` which solves this and similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

`"0$SomeString"` is a double-quoted string. It contains the character "0" followed by the contents of the variable `$SomeString`.

If that's not clear, please explain which part of it is confusing you.